# Affine transformation mapping circle to ellipse

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, conic-sections

I'm trying to find an affine transformation that maps the unit circle to an ellipse centered at $(1,3)$ such that points P$(-3,-1)$ and R$(5,7)$ are at the greatest distance from the centre of the ellipse along the major axis while points Q$(0,4)$ and S$(2,2)$ are at the greatest distance from the centre of the ellipse along the minor axis.

I think we need to rotate the unit disc followed by scaling and then another rotation. But I don't know how to find the matrix that does that. Ultimately, I think there will be translation by $(1,3)^T.$

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints :**

- $(5,7), (1,3), (-3,-1)$ lie on line $y=mx+c$
- $(0,4), (1,3), (2,2)$ lie on line $y=\ldots$
- Conclude this is rotation with $\theta = \tan^{-1} m$
- Use [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)
  $$ \begin{bmatrix} 
  \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
  \sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$
- Find lengths of axes of ellipse. Hence find scaling matrix. $$ \begin{bmatrix} 
  a & 0 \\
  0 & b \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$

Comment: So, am I right in saying that we have to rotate the unit disc by the rotation matrix where $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$ followed by scaling matrix where $a$ and $b$ are $4$ and $1$ respectively and then translation by $(1,3)^T$ ? So do we only need one rotation ?

Comment: @Rhombus Almost! It's $4\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Yes. Only one rotation is required.